# How to get property values of object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object which has multiple properties and values. How do I fetch all at once?

In this below code the products have multiple values. I want to grab all the prices and want the sum of them using java script

The code as follows.

```
var products = [
    {name:"anti-glair", price:100, quantity:200, status:"available"},
    {name:"Lens", price:300, quantity:35, status:"Un-available"},
    {name:"Optics", price:150, quantity:500, status:"available"}
    ];
```

I am trying like this

```
console.log(products.price);
```

But it is showing as not defined.

I want the all products sum as well.

Comment: *"...how do i fetch all at once."* What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean to get all values at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`products` refers to an array. You can access the first object in that array using index 0, the second using index 1, etc. Or you can loop through the array using a `for` loop, `products.forEach`, or a number of other ways outlined in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).

Once you have the object, you can access its properties using the syntax you've shown.

So for instance:

```js
var products = [
    {name:"anti-glair", price:100, quantity:200, status:"available"},
    {name:"Lens", price:300, quantity:35, status:"Un-available"},
    {name:"Optics", price:150, quantity:500, status:"available"}
    ];
console.log(products[0].price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use higher order functions. To get an array of prices,

```
let prices = products.map(x => x.price)
```

Then to sum that,

```
let totalCost = prices.reduce((x, y) => x + y)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** this, this is what you want.

```js
var products = [
    {name:"anti-glair", price:100, quantity:200, status:"available"},
    {name:"Lens", price:300, quantity:35, status:"Un-available"},
    {name:"Optics", price:150, quantity:500, status:"available"}
    ];

var TotalPrice = 0;
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i< products.length; i++){
  TotalPrice = TotalPrice + products[i].price;
  obj[i] = { price : products[i].price};
}
obj.total_price = TotalPrice;

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Tank You :) M.Tanzil

Answer (score 0):

For iterating and getting sum or price use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```
var sum = products.reduce(function(a, b) {
  // calculate the price and add with total
  // multiply with `quantity` property if you want
  return a + b.price;
  // set initial value as 0
}, 0);
```

```js
var products = [{
  name: "anti-glair",
  price: 100,
  quantity: 200,
  status: "available"
}, {
  name: "Lens",
  price: 300,
  quantity: 35,
  status: "Un-available"
}, {
  name: "Optics",
  price: 150,
  quantity: 500,
  status: "available"
}];

var sum = products.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.price;
}, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get first the length of the object before iterating the rest of the data:

```js
var products = [
    {name:"anti-glair", price:100, quantity:200, status:"available"},
    {name:"Lens", price:300, quantity:35, status:"Un-available"},
    {name:"Optics", price:150, quantity:500, status:"available"}
    ];

var sumPrices = 0;
for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  console.log("Name: " + products[i].name + ", Price: " + products[i].price + ", Quantity: " + products[i].quantity[i] + ", Status: " + products[i].status);  
  sumPrices = sumPrices + products[i].price; 
}
console.log("Total sum of prices: " + sumPrices);
```